# getJSON loading to slow, .toggle() not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, getjson

**Purpose** = toggle a section 'more info' for a specific item in a list
**Problem** = a simple jQuery `.toggle()` isn't working
**Possible** cause = getJSON loads to slow

I am loading a foursquare json to get venues around my current location. I then `.append()` those venues with jQuery to my HTML. After that I have a function to toggle a section with 'more info' on a click-event.

After some searching I think I found the problem. My getJSON **starts** loading and then my next function is loaded in jQuery. After this next function is loaded (which is my `.toggle()`) the getJSON finally finishes. So I think my function with my `.toggle()` can't find the classes to toggle, because they are not yet in my HTML because my getJSON isn't finished loading the data.

Here is my [jQuery code](https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/5f4da82998a1f2cfd85f).
And the output of my console in my browser has this order:

```
loaded 4sq venues                    line 29
toggle function loaded               line 33
200                                  line 10
```

It's because of this `meta.code` on line 10 that I believe the getJSON is to slow loading...

I hope I made myself clear enough.
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you do the oath - when requesting, the url, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async.

Comment: I replaced the client_id and client_secret with 'placeholder'.

Comment: Also, you marked this as duplicate.. Could you give me the original post? I didn't find it.. I always check stackoverflow before creating a new question. Thanks

Comment: the question linked at the top is the duplicate, it should explain the concepts of how to deal with async in jquery.

Comment: Thanks, i'll read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add your `click` event to body like

```
$('body').on('click', '.venueLabel', function(){
     $(".venueMore").toggle("slow");
});
```

Because you add elements dynamically!

Comment: Thanks Michael, this worked indeed!! There is just a small typo in your code above, see the dot before the function needs to be a comma.

Comment: !! Just uploaded it and tested this on chrome/firefox/safari and all the mobile versions of that. Works perfectly except on Safari iOS, nothing happening there..

Answer (score 0):

getJSON is going to be asynchronous. Which means it won't stop other Javascript from running while it's doing it's thing.

You should use a callback in `getFoursquareVenues`. Example below.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    getFoursquareVenues(openDetailVenues());
});

function getFoursquareVenues(callback) {

    $.getJSON("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=placeholder&client_secret=placeholder&v=20130815&ll=51.0824401,3.714485&query=cafe", function(data) {

        console.log(data.meta.code);

        $('#venueList').html();
        var content = '';

        $.each(data.response.venues, function(index, elm) {
            content += '' + '<div class="venue col-xs-12">' + '<div class="venueLabel" id="' + elm.id + '">' + elm.name + '</div>' + '<div class="venueMore">' + elm.location.address + elm.hereNow.count + '</div>' + '</div>'
        });
        $('#venueList').append(content);

        if (callback) { callback() };
    });
    console.log('loaded 4sq venues');
}

function openDetailVenues() {
    console.log('toggle function loaded');
    $(".venueLabel").click(function() {
        $(".venueMore").toggle("slow");
    });
}
```